# Portal for reviews about potential employers for US[IT]

Tags: employer, review

In Germany, there is a well known, major portal [Kununu](https://www.kununu.com/us/2) to learn about potential employers (reviews). Is there any major one for the US ? If there is not a major portal but several ones, an example would nevertheless help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's easily answered via Google search.

Comment: sorry, but I disagree...of crs you find hits if you search via Google. But the portals are more or less all 'international' and for a non-US citizen it's not that transparent, which portal(s) have their focus on the US...

Comment: Great question, thanks for asking.  I'd like to know this too.  i believe glassdoor.com may be one in the US?

Comment: @Hawk66 Type in the name of a potential employer and see if the site contains the information you're looking for. The major players here seem to make it very clear which location any given review is coming from (in case the company has many locations), so I don't really see why you disagree with simply Googling it. Also, this data depends on where people choose to post it, so it's not just a case of "X contains everything you need", you might need to try different ones.

Comment: @alroc "Can be found via a Google search" is not a reason to close-vote, but this question does seem too broad though.

Comment: @Dukeling - Yes, if all you wanted was GlassDoor you could easily find it on the first page of Google results. Looking through databases, ratings (S&P, Stock Market, etc.) and other means to confirm if it's useful or schilling is always advisable. Saying just goto one place well known is like answering 'just Google it' - people should know *that* much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any major one for the US ?

### Glassdoor

There is something similar to that here in the USA, called Glassdoor.  I don't know all the ins and outs of it, but here it the link [Glassdoor Company Reviews](https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/index.htm).  There may be others, but this is the big one used by most people I know.

Comment: thx, that was what I'am asking for :)

Answer (score 1):

**Employee resources:** Obtain inside (and outside) information about businesses.

**Be aware:** Some review sites permit reviews to be removed for a fee and anyone can make a glowing review, or multiple ones. This is why the alternative links at the bottom are offered.

With large companies (especially multinational) there usually are several divisions thru-out the USA and multiple offices throughout the world. One division's management could stink while another division's management team could make for a friendly and nurturing workplace.

**USA**

- Reviews and a Blog with articles: https://www.comparably.com/
- Reviews: https://www.careerbliss.com/
- One of the best known and quite comprehensive: https://www.GlassDoor.com/
- Branching out into the USA is Germany's: https://www.kununu.com/us/
- Focused on Accounting, Banking, Consulting and Law firm reviews, but is branching out into Technology: http://www.vault.com/

**Remember to:** Check the business' own website, if it's broken, ugly, poor spelling, or just plain tells you that they don't do the work you're looking for that's a hint to move on.

I've even seen carefully sabotaged webpages that gave incorrect information or showed photos that made you wonder what is going on there - it was like the company didn't check their own website (or maybe a disgruntled employee changed the password after making a mess).

Don't forget about the company's FaceBook, LinkedIn and YouTube pages.

---

**Other**

Advertising themselves as "Job, Company Reviews, and Career Advice for Women" there's: https://fairygodboss.com/

- A Canada only review website: http://ratemyemployer.ca/
- An Australia only review website: https://www.jobadvisor.org/
- Austria, Germany, Switzerland and the USA: https://www.kununu.com/
- An India only review website: http://www.jobeehive.com/reviews-ratings
- A UK based review website:http://www.thejobcrowd.com/ - just started reviewing.

---

**Company Research:**

Not reviews but databases about basic info (who owns it, how many divisions, how many employees, sales, even profit and Stock info).

http://www.hoovers.com/

https://www.wetfeet.com/

The [Fortune 500](http://money.cnn.com/magazines/fortune/fortune500/) List, [100 Fastest Growing Companies](http://money.cnn.com/magazines/fortune/fortunefastestgrowing/2007/), and [100 Best Companies to Work for](http://archive.fortune.com/magazines/fortune/bestcompanies/2008/) are also other valuable research avenues. Not *just* lists but ***why*** they are great places to work.

---

In addition to Employer Review Websites be certain to check customer driven reviews and business standards organizations.

Regardless of what people say about working there the customer's opinion about the business is also important. Check out:

- The [Better Business Bureau](https://www.bbb.org/) has minimum standards that businesses are expected to meet for their customers, they don't accept employee complaints.
- [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/) allows you to literally walk around the neighborhood and check out the appearance of the neighboring businesses, find restaurants or competitors nearby, plan your route to and from, see reviews from people whom may be employees, customers, the owner's friends or enemies.
- [Yelp](https://www.yelp.com/locations) contains mostly restaurant reviews (which are useful if you don't like finding room in a tiny fridge for a bag lunch). Increasingly non-restaurant reviews are appearing but it's still a bit light compared to other resources.

---

Info and Resources for Job Search (not employer reviews) is also important for choosing a career, polishing up your resume, or yourself:

Career Advice: https://www.indeed.com/forum/gen/Career-Advice.html and https://www.monster.ca/career-advice/ - Canadian based but applicable throughout North America.